# Admittance matrix when switch is open

Tags: switches, power-grid, admittance

In the following there is an example of an admittance matrix.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_admittance_matrix

If y13 had a switch and it is open, what happens to the admittance matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a power distribution engineer, but reading the article in the link you provided I see

> It is important to note that \$y_{ki}\$ is non-zero only where a physical connection exists between two buses.

Which I interpret to imply breaking the 1-3 connection by means of a switch would mean $$y_{13} = y_{31} = 0$$

Comment: ee.se uses `\$<math>\$` instead of just `$<math>$` for inline math, to avoid breaking posts that talk about the dollar cost of something.